# Outlook/Exchange restore recently deleted mails

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I just had a problem with my keyboard. The blutooth dongle lost connection or something like that, and Outlook interpreted that as a pressed "Delete" key.

Now, somewhere between 200 and 500 mails from the folder I was working in are in my deleted objects; completely mixed with all mails I knowingly and willingly deleted elsewhere during the last weeks.

Can I somehow restore the mails that were deleted during a certain timeframe?

The Account is bound to an Exchange account, if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

1. Go to your "**Deleted Items**" folder
2. Right click the columns headers and click "**View Settings**"
3. Click "**Columns...**" button
4. Change "**Select available columns from:**" drop-down menu to "**All mail fields**"
5. Click to highlight "**Modified**" from the left list of available fields
6. Click "**Add ->**" to add the item to your current view
7. Click "**OK**"
8. Click "**OK**" again - you will now see the "Modified" field as a new column in your "Deleted Items" folder
9. Adjust the column width so you can see the date/time the mail items were last modified
10. Click the "**Modified**" header title which will organise the folder items into the modified order of your choice (ascending/descending).

Hopefully this might now show messages that were modified outside of their "received" date/time (i.e. a move of the email). I tested this by moving an old email from my deleted items back into my Inbox and then moving it back into my deleted items and it was now listed at the top of my view (as I'd sorted the list by "Modified").

Unfortunately you may need to select the emails and manually move them back into your Inbox because I know not of any "undo" functionality within Outlook.

Comment: I don't know how ubiquitous it is, but I'm looking at an undo button in my work Outlook (Outlook 2013), and I even used it today. I don't know if it's related to server settings or if it's just normally hidden.

Answer (score 0):

When ***Outlook interpreted that as a pressed "Delete" key***, it means the items have been deleted one by one, other than at the same time. In this situation, when you click undo icon, it just moves the last deleted message back to the previous folder, other than all items which were deleted during that period.

So the easiest way would be manually moving these deleted items back to previous folder, just like @Kinnectus suggested.